# Using Fuelt API to create a database with Code First approach

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to create a database with Code First approach. Reading some tutorials they use Fluent API but when I try this it shows a "missing a reference" message on "HasForeignKey".

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.FKId);
    }
```

My solution set up is that I have a DAL project with all database related stuff and a .NET Core 2.2 WebApplication. How can I use Fluent API?

Comment: Add the missing reference or namespace. I'd bet Visual Studio displays a quick-fix on the left of the line offering to add the correct namespace, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it part of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package? Becouse I can't find it. ANd VS is not showing a quick fix.